# What ghost in the machine is changing Safari Privacy settings? Mail, too?

Tags: macos, mail.app, safari, preferences

Safari, Mail. What on earth?

Occasionally, Mail can't connect, so I go into Preferences .. and every time, a password has just plain disappeared.

Or I'll go thru Safari Preferences and discover, under Privacy, that "Block Cookies From Third Parties," the first checkbox, has been mysteriously *checked* ... but I use [Cookie](http://sweetpproductions.com) (cookie manager and more) so *I* always check "Never."

Also find the two other Privacy choices will be not as I set them. That pane seems to be the worst culprit.

Thoughts? As well as how this relates to the Mail mystery?

OS 10.8.4, Safari 6.0.5 on MBPro, maintenance and repair up to snuff.

Comment: Does someone has a remote access to your computer ?

Comment: This has been happening to me also.  Malware scans show only Windows malware in email attachments.  Mail server ports changed, check boxes turned on or off, passwords erased, websites finding out my location, and more.  Some of the changes were done by software update, but the ones that happened yesterday were not.  Sure would like an answer.  Tempted to put the O.S. in a VM with my documents outside of the VM, and reload the original VM at boot-time.